# How should I go about making my verb conjugation study tool in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, random

Thanks for taking the time to look at my post, I am a student in a Spanish class right now and I want to make a study tool to practice Spanish verb conjugations.

After talking with a code academy advisor, he recommended using nested dictionaries, which you can see in my code below.

- The level 1 keys should be the infinitive forms of all verbs included.
- The level 2 keys should be the tenses of the verb.
- The level 3 keys should be personal pronouns and the level 3 values should be the corresponding verbs marked by person and number that we want to learn.

I am unfamiliar with these dictionaries and need help! The code academy advisor briefly went over randomization before his shift ended. Here are the 3 mains things I want inside my game:

1. Having the program randomly select a verb, a tense, and an article.
2. Having the program ask for user input and ask a question, such as, "What is the (tense) (article) form of (verb)?"
3. Having the program respond, saying "Correct!" or "Wrong!"

Some examples:

- Example 1:

  - Program question: What is the present yo form of hacer?
  - User input: Hago
  - Program response "Correct!"
- Example 2:

  - Program question: What is the present tu form of hacer?
  - User input: Haces
  - Program response "Correct!"
- Example 3:

  - Program question: What is the preterite yo form of hacer?
  - User input: Hece
  - Program response "Incorrect!"

Here are my dictionaries at the moment

```
import random  
verbs = {
'hacer': {
'present':{
    'yo': 'hago',
    'tu': 'haces',
    'elellausted': 'hace',
    'nosotros': 'hacemos',
    'ellosellasuds': 'hacen'
}
, 'preterite':{
    'yo': 'hice',
    'tu': 'hiciste',
    'elellausted': 'hizo',
    'nosotros': 'hicimos',
    'ellosellasuds': 'hicieron'
}
}
'tener': {
'present':{
    'yo': 'tengo',
    'tu': 'tienes',
    'elellaud':'tiene',
    'nosotros':'tenemos' ,
    'ellosellasuds':'tienen'
}
, 'preterite':{
    'yo': 'tuve',
    'tu': 'tuviste',
    'elellausted': 'tuvo',
    'nosotros': 'tuvimos',
    'ellosellasuds': 'tuvieron'
}
}
}
```

Thank you to anyone out there that can help me out! I just beginning to program, but I've been doing website design for around 6 months now. I am willing to learn and any help would be greatly appreciated.

If you would like to setup a skype call of some sort or chat about this, that would be greatly appreciated and I would be more than willing!

Again, thanks for reading.

Comment: I suggest you read more about using dictionaries in python. Once you understand simple dictionaries, nested ones will make a lot more sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a few moments, so here's some code that should help you get going. It first creates lists of the possible articles, verbs and tenses (these could be found using for loops, or manually entered by you). It then uses the `random` module to choose a random entry from these lists. We then ask the user for their answer, giving them a new question if they get it right, and allowing them to try again otherwise. 
Let me know if there's anything you don't understand.

```
import random  
verbs = {
'hacer': {
'present':{
    'yo': 'hago',
    'tu': 'haces',
    'elellausted': 'hace',
    'nosotros': 'hacemos',
    'ellosellasuds': 'hacen'
}
, 'preterite':{
    'yo': 'hice',
    'tu': 'hiciste',
    'elellausted': 'hizo',
    'nosotros': 'hicimos',
    'ellosellasuds': 'hicieron'
}
}, # ADDED A MISSING COMMA HERE
'tener': {
'present':{
    'yo': 'tengo',
    'tu': 'tienes',
    'elellaud':'tiene',
    'nosotros':'tenemos' ,
    'ellosellasuds':'tienen'
}
, 'preterite':{
    'yo': 'tuve',
    'tu': 'tuviste',
    'elellausted': 'tuvo',
    'nosotros': 'tuvimos',
    'ellosellasuds': 'tuvieron'
    }
    }
    }

article_list = ["yo", "tu", "elellausted", "nosotros", "ellosellasuds"]
verb_list = list(verbs.keys())

tense_list = []
for key in verbs:
  for tense in verbs[key]:
    if tense not in tense_list:
      tense_list.append(tense)
# or you could just manually type a list of tenses, probably more efficient. 

while True:
  article_choice = random.choice(article_list)
  verb_choice = random.choice(verb_list)
  tense_choice = random.choice(tense_list)

  question = "What is the {} {} form of {}?\n> ".format(tense_choice, article_choice, verb_choice)

  while True:
    response = input("{}".format(question)) #in python2: raw_input(..)

    if verbs[verb_choice][tense_choice][article_choice] == response.lower().strip():
      print("Correct!")
      break
    else:
      print("Incorrect, try again.")
```

Answer (score 4):

## TL;DR

I added a few features to Windmill's code - a verb score counter that is saved that helps to prioritize low score conjugations, some options to skip or quit, I saved the dict as json in a file and I also added some advice for webscraping verbs.

## Study tool

- Goal: ease the study of verbs by testing the user on verbs they regularly fail on.

### Use case

Note that I came across this post while also searching for the same general use case.

Namely, 'I want to study the verbs in language X and improve by using a small program.'

To be specific, I also needed a verb conjugation study tool as I am studying Portuguese. Portuguese is a language similar to Spanish in a few aspects, one of which is verb conjugation.

I also considered the fact that you want a **verb conjugation study tool**, which I think is what the question generally alludes to - the use of this tool is not only limited to Spanish. From the question I understood that the study tool should help you study - e.g. adapt *with* you as you learn, and prioritize words you get wrong consistently and it should be easy to understand how it works.

### A design that targets weakness

Basically, we want to track our scores to target our weaknesses, otherwise the program will go back to verbs we already know well*. I think this is important in such a study tool otherwise it will be a waste of time to use.

* It may be an idea to add information about whether a verb is regular or irregular. That way we would be able to prioritize irregular verbs after regular forms in a certain tense are understood well. 'Well' here could be decided by the user of the tool heuristically, or empirically, as a research question. Both depend on the needs of the user and the information the tool stores.

### Getting the data

First and foremost we need the verb table data.

You have a choice to either put in the data manually, which either takes a lot of tedium and patience, or automatically, which takes a willingness to learn if you don't know webscraping. I recommend that you lookup webscraping in python so you can learn to construct the basic commands needed to fetch your verbs with some libraries like requests and lxml or beautifulsoup. It is up to you which website(s) you decide to scrape as there are many online dictionaries available to scrape with information about verb inflections.

#### Data Format choices

When saving the scraped data, you have some choices.

json

If you want to use a dictionary, I recommend saving it as json file and loading using the python json library. That way you can keep the file apart from the code.

So your verbs would look something like this in a file named `spanish_verbs.json`:

```
{
  "hacer": {
    "present": {
      "yo": "hago",
      "tu": "haces",
      "elellausted": "hace",
      "nosotros": "hacemos",
      "ellosellasuds": "hacen"
    },
    "preterite": {
      "yo": "hice",
      "tu": "hiciste",
      "elellausted": "hizo",
      "nosotros": "hicimos",
      "ellosellasuds": "hicieron"
    }
  },
  "tener": {
    "present": {
      "yo": "tengo",
      "tu": "tienes",
      "elellaud": "tiene",
      "nosotros": "tenemos",
      "ellosellasuds": "tienen"
    },
    "preterite": {
      "yo": "tuve",
      "tu": "tuviste",
      "elellausted": "tuvo",
      "nosotros": "tuvimos",
      "ellosellasuds": "tuvieron"
    }
  }
}
```

So now instead of having the verbs in the program, you can load them with something simple like:

```py
with open("spanish_verbs.json", 'r') as f:
      verbs = json.load(f)
```

csv

Otherwise I would save the data as csv or tsv and use something like pandas to load the file.

### Program actions and interface

The current interface is terminal based. If you wanted to go further you could use something like tkinter or wxpython to build a GUI.

### Starting the program

Starting the program from the terminal:

```sh
python3 ./ask_verb_tense_example.py spanish_verbs.json verb_scores.tsv
```

#### Actions

The actions you can use are either

1. to type a verb and press return to check whether you are correct

- By running this command you can either be correct or incorrect

or

2. to select an option and press return

regarding the options, you can select

- q - to save progress and quit
- p - to pass and show the verb that the user couldn't remember
- These options assume there shouldn't be any verbs called q or p.

### Keeping track of scores

There is also a verb scores dataframe in the program that is updated and tracks and trains you on a random verb from a set of your 5 poorest scoring verbs after you have gone through all the verbs once.

#### Scoring Rules

The scoring rules are as follows:

- typing a correct answer will add one to the correct cumulative score for the verb
- typing an incorrect answer will add one to the incorrect cumulative score for the verb
- passing will add one to the incorrect cumulative score for the verb
- any of the above actions will add one to the total variable, which is tracked to check the percentage of incorrect/correct answers

## Code

here is the code:

```py
import random
import readline
import sys
import os
import json
import pandas as pd

with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
   verbs = json.load(f)

def load_verb_scores(filename):
   if not os.path.exists(filename):
       verb_scores = pd.DataFrame(
           {
               "verb": pd.Series([], dtype='str'),
               "correct": pd.Series([], dtype='int'),
               "incorrect": pd.Series([], dtype='int'),
               "total": pd.Series([], dtype='int'),
           },
       )
   else:
       verb_scores = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\t')
   return verb_scores

def update_scores(verb_scores, verb, correct=False, incorrect=False):
   total=0

   if correct and incorrect:
       raise Exception("Answer to question cannot be both correct and incorrect!")

   if (verb_scores.verb==verb).any():

       if correct:
           verb_scores.loc[(verb_scores.verb==verb),"correct"]+=1

       elif incorrect:
           verb_scores.loc[(verb_scores.verb==verb),"incorrect"]+=1

       verb_scores.loc[(verb_scores.verb==verb),"total"]+=1

   else:
       verb_scores=verb_scores.append(
           {
               "verb":verb,
               "correct":int(correct),
               "incorrect":int(incorrect),
               "total":1,
           },
           ignore_index=True
       )


   return verb_scores

verb_scores = load_verb_scores(sys.argv[2])
total_to_practice = sum([len(y) for v in verbs.values() for y in v.values()])
print(f"found {total_to_practice} verbs to practice")

while True:

   if verb_scores.shape[0]==total_to_practice:
       # random choice out of poorest performing verbs
       poorest_performance = (verb_scores.incorrect/verb_scores.total).nlargest(5).index
       verb = random.choice(verb_scores.loc[poorest_performance].verb.tolist())

       v_index=verb_scores.verb==verb

       # warning: some verbs may correspond to multiple infinitives/tenses/articles !
       infinitive = [i for i, v in verbs.items() for y in v.values() if verb in y.values()][0]
       tense = [t for v in verbs.values() for t, y in v.items() if verb in y.values()][0]
       article = [a for a,v in verbs.get(infinitive).get(tense).items() if verb==v][0]

       incorrect_pct = (verb_scores[v_index].incorrect*100/verb_scores[v_index].total).item()
       print("selected verb: ", infinitive, " wrong ", incorrect_pct, "% of the time")

   else:
       # random choice over all verbs to begin with
       infinitive = random.choice(list(verbs.keys()))

       tense2articles2verbs = verbs.get(infinitive)
       tense = random.choice(list(tense2articles2verbs.keys())) # choose a tense
       articles2verbs = tense2articles2verbs.get(tense)
       article = random.choice(list(articles2verbs.keys())) # choose an article
       verb = articles2verbs.get(article)

   question = "What is the {} {} form of {}?\n> ".format(
       tense,
       article,
       infinitive,
   )

   while True:
       response = input("{}".format(question))

       if verb == response.lower().strip():
           print("\033[92mCorrect!\033[0m")
           verb_scores = update_scores(
               verb_scores,
               verb,
               correct=True
           )
           break
       elif 'p' == response.lower():
           print("\033[91mPassing... the correct verb was {}\033[0m".format(verb))
           verb_scores = update_scores(
               verb_scores,
               verb,
               incorrect=True
           )
           break
       elif 'q' == response.lower():
           print("Safe quit.")
           verb_scores.to_csv(sys.argv[2], sep='\t', index=False)
           sys.exit(0)
       else:
           verb_scores = update_scores(
               verb_scores,
               verb,
               incorrect=True
           )

           print("\033[91mIncorrect, try again.\033[0m")
```

### Example output

The program output looks like this:

```
What is the present nosotros form of hacer?
> hacemos
Correct!
```

After you have gone through all verbs possible, it will start running through the top 5 verbs that you tend to get wrong the most.

```
$ python3 ./ask_verb_tense_example.py spanish_verbs.json verb_scores.tsv
found 20 verbs to practice
selected verb:  tener  wrong  100.0 % of the time
What is the preterite tu form of tener?
> tenes
Incorrect, try again.
...
```

### The scores file

You can also visit the verb scores file called `verb_scores.tsv` that was created and updated by the program after the user hit q to save and quit. In this way you can track your progress by importing the tsv into some spreadsheet software for example.

```
verb     correct   incorrect  total
hacemos  0         3          3
tiene    1         1          2
```